How to handle merge conflicts in Azure DevOps when commits exist on both develop and master branches
When trying to complete a pull request (PR) that merges our develop branch into master in Azure DevOps (using rebase and fast-forward), a merge conflict occurs if some commits already exist on master. This happens when commits have been pushed to both develop and master before the merge attempt (for example, when a hotfix is pushed directly to master to address a production issue).
Is there a way to configure Azure DevOps to automatically skip commits that are already present on master during the merge process?
Alternatively, would it be better to adopt a workflow where we build and publish from release branches, allowing hotfixes to be merged into the release branch instead of master, avoiding the need to cherry-pick commits to master?
Note: Force-pushing to the master branch is not an option due to compliance restrictions. Additionally, I’m part of a small backend team that frequently releases new production builds.

You should made change on release branch. Master branch should not be edited directly. Then you will not have conflict and cleaner flow.
Maybe creating a hot-fix branch will help with tracking hot-fixes.
